# Unable to compress a CSV file Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to convert an existing CSV file to a gzip file.

I verified the CSV looks good. Once I run this code, I get a "failed to expand" error and tried an online decompression tool that also failed, so it seems the output zip is corrupt.

```
    public void compressGzip(String input, String dest) throws IOException {

        Path pathSource = Paths.get(input);
        Path destSource = Paths.get(dest);

        try (GZIPOutputStream gos = new GZIPOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(destSource.toFile()));
             FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(pathSource.toFile())) {

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                gos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }

        }
    }
```

[image]

Anything I could be missing here?

Comment: The while loop hits one iteration

Comment: You're code works okay for me

Comment: @MadProgrammer any chance /tmp directory would affect this at all ? Mac OS

Comment: @Ryan No idea, I'm running on MacOS as well, trying to find a large file

Comment: @Ryan Yes, maybe try expanding into a more public space.  I zip a 36mb video file and had no issue decompressing it (using my Downloads folder)

Comment: Interesting. I'm testing with a small file (1KB). Surprised it's not working. I have a single mount point on my k8s cluster underneath /tmp so a bit tied down with this path when I deploy

Comment: Just curious, and not sure it matters, but if you're using GZIP streams, why does your destination file have a `.zip` extension? Shouldn't it be `.gz`?

Comment: I agree with slaw. I was just about to suggest the same. Rename the file to .gz and try to open it. Also try to open with a other utility like 7zip.

Comment: gz extension didn't make a difference